# Z-index not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

Hi I have a close button on the container and i am trying to create two different click events. When a user click on the close button then it should call the close button click event and when click on the container it should call the container click event.

The container click event is working fine but when clicking on the close button then it is calling both close click event and the contianer click event. I have set the `z-index:9999` to the close div but still this is not working.

This is my  [Jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/10311/) .

```
$( "#close-button-landscape" ).click(function() {
  alert( "close button click" );
});
$( "#container" ).click(function() {
  alert( "container click" );
});
```

Thanks for the answers. In the Jquery i can use `event.stopPropagation();` but what if click events are not using Jquery and pure javascript . See this [updated Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/10313/), then how to stop the bubble event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to do something called stop propagation

```
 $( "#close-button-landscape" ).click(function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  alert( "close button click" );
});
```

this prevents the click event from bubbling up to the container one as well.

Note: z-index won't affect anything in this case. z-index only paints elements out of order ... and the area which #container covers is larger than the one that the close button affects

Comment: and what if i want to do it using javascript?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed do you mean vanilla js?

Comment: no i mean pure javascript without using jquery can you check the updated jsfiddle link i sent you

Comment: @OwaisAhmed for future reference vanilla js == pure js == native js

Comment: thanks for this i did not know this particular word :)

Comment: @OwaisAhmed there's no difference between mine or native js btw, just put the stoppropagation method at the end instead of at the top (jquery will queue it correctly, js will not)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99357/discussion-between-daemedeor-and-owais-ahmed).

Comment: Thanks i got the answer evt.stopPropagation(); is working for vanilla.js as well thanks

Comment: @OwaisAhmed note that pure JS `stopPropagation` did not work on IE < 9, where you would need to use `cancelBubble`. The jQuery version hides this from you and handles all that transparently. See [sanepete's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34539338/3527940) which is actually pure JS-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The button is still in the container so you have to stop the click getting through:

```
$('#close-button-landscape').click(function(event)
{
 event=event||window.event;
 if(event.stopPropagation)
 {
  event.stopPropagation();
 }
 else
 {
  event.cancelBubble=true;
 }
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to do it using javascript?

Comment: Note that when using jQuery, you actually don't need all of that: jQuery will always provide an `event` as an argument, and that event will always support `stopPropagation`. So `event.stopPropagation();` is enough. You need all that stuff for pure JS, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use stopPropagation

```
$( "#close-button-landscape" ).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert( "close button click" );
});
$( "#container" ).click(function() {
  alert( "container click" );
});
```